# Understanding various ctrl-r variants in vim

Tags: vimrc

I will use [`ctrl-r`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-R) quite frequently in insert mode to insert contents of a register, for example, `"`, `%`, or any of the [a-z] registers. I've also come across the following in the help:

```
tag             char                         action in Insert mode   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
i_CTRL-R        CTRL-R {register}            insert the contents of a register
i_CTRL-R_CTRL-R CTRL-R CTRL-R {register}     insert the contents of a register literally
i_CTRL-R_CTRL-O CTRL-R CTRL- O {register}    insert the contents of a register literally and don't auto-indent
i_CTRL-R_CTRL-P CTRL-R CTRL-P {register}     insert the contents of a register literally and fix indent.
```

What exactly is the difference between these? For example, for the `insert register literally` I was thinking that it would convert something like a newline into a control-sequence, so the text:

```
Hello

There
```

Would be converted to something like:

```
Hello^JThere
```

But that doesn't seem to be the case. Could someone explain the differences between the four `ctrl-r` options perhaps using an example for how the four would actually produce a different output when pasted into vim?

Comment: `:help i_CTRL-R_CTRL-R` explains the difference and includes an example.

Comment: @Rich yes it does include an example for `ab^Hc`. I was more curious about some more extensive examples -- lists, dicts, strings with actual newlines and tabs in it, etc., etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good example to illustrate this is by creating a list and inserting it with [`CTRL-R`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-R) and [`CTRL-R CTRL-R`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-R_CTRL-R).

```
:let a=[1,2,3,4]
```

Now if we insert the contents of `a` using `ctrl-r`, the list will appear, with one element per line:

```
1
2
3
4
```

However, if we insert the contents of `a` using `ctrl-r` `ctrl-r`, we will see the list-separator (`NUL`) on that line:

```
1^@2^@3^@4^@
```

The two other variants, [`CTRL-R CTRL-O`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-R_CTRL-O) and [`CTRL-R CTRL-P`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-R_CTRL-P) are the based on the latter, except the former will not auto-indent and the latter will.

In case a more-visual example is helpful:

[image]

Comment: Hm, i wonder if you can do the same thing with a register

Comment: @D.BenKnoble what do you mean by that?

Comment: Well, here you used the expression register. But what about yanked text or `let @a=...` or a recorded macro? Just curious.

Comment: `:help i_CTRL-R_CTRL-R` suggests it matters when the register contains control characters like backspace.

Comment: I think this answer would benefit from an example that explains the difference between the final three versions, `<C-R><C-R>`, `<C-R><C-O>`, and `<C-R><C-P>`, as the Vim documentation doesn't include such an example.

Comment: @Rich would you want to post an answer and I can accept this. Actually this was sort of my investigation to my questions and really just notes to myself!